# Firefox label element border cut off with position relative

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have some custom check boxes that I am working with. When you select them the focus class gets added to them. When that happens a border appears around it. For most browsers the border appears like a square around the label element. Though in firefox the left border gets cut off. If you remove position relative this correct the issue. Though I do not want to do that for positioning purposes. I created a dumbed down example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/g617z4qk/3/

Notice when you look in firefox how it looks different then chrome. How can I make firefox behave like chrome?

here is the html code:

```
<div class="textContainter">
  <label class="input-control checkbox focus">"
     <input id="classAll" class="classAll input-control" type="checkbox" name="status" value="Item 1" tabindex="-1" checked="checked" />
     <span class="input-control-img"></span>
     <span class="input-control-text">test Item 1</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
label.input-control {
    display: inline-block;
}
.textContainter .focus {
    outline: 1px dotted !important;
 }
.input-control, .input-control .input-control-body {
   position:relative;
 }

 label.input-control input {
    left: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
 }

 label.input-control.checkbox .input-control-img {
    background-image: url("http://blogs.digitss.com/wp-      content/uploads/2010/04/fancy-radio-checkbox.png");
 }
 label.input-control .input-control-img {
   background-position: 0 0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 20px;
 }
 label.input-control span {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This positioning of the input elements to the far left

```
label.input-control input {
    left: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

makes the label outline expand to the left as well (at least in Firefox).

Simply adding `overflow:hidden` for the `label` elements should fix that:

```
label.input-control {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g617z4qk/5/

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround. Replace the outline with border and it works fine on both the browsers you have mentioned.

This issues seems to be a duplicate of [CSS "outline" different behavior behavior on Webkit & Gecko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662902/css-outline-different-behavior-behavior-on-webkit-gecko)

The JSfiddle for the workaround is
`border: 1px dotted;` http://jsfiddle.net/g617z4qk/4/