# Get size of elements bounding box

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get the size of the `bounding box` of an element with pure JS?
And by `bounding box` I mean **the size of the square that will be created if I surround all the visible elements in that element**.

`offsetWidth`/`offsetHeight` and `scrollWidth`/`scrollHeight` won't do because the size of that square depends on the `overflow` value of the element and they don't.

Example with and without `overflow:hidden`:

```js
var first = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0];
var second = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0];

console.log(first.offsetHeight)
console.log(first.scrollHeight)
console.log(first.getBoundingClientRect())

console.log(second.offsetHeight)
console.log(second.scrollHeight)
console.log(second.getBoundingClientRect())
```

```css
.out {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.in {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  top: 150px;
}
.second {
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first out">
  <div class="in">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="second out">
  <div class="in">
  </div>
</div>
```

`.in` in the `.first` element is visible, so the `.first` bounding box height should include it ( it should be 200, which is actually the `scrollHeight` ).
But, `.in` in the `.second` element, is not visible, so the `.second` bounding box height shouldn't include it ( it should be 50, which is actually the `offsetHeight`)

So, neither `offsetHeight` nor `scrollHeight` can give you the `bounding box` height, unless you know the `overflow` value of the element.

Comment: does `.getBoundingClientRect` give you what you need? ... or `.getClientRects`

Comment: "*..Although the red and blue outlines are different in height...*" -- how?

Comment: @Abhitalks What do you mean _"how"_?

Comment: something is not quite right with the question i agree with Abhitalks, also why overflow matter, there is no outer box for "second".

Comment: @JaromandaX  No, they won't do, if you run the snippet and look at the console you will see they produce the same results.

Comment: sorry, I didn't even see you already tried those

Comment: @vtz There is a red outline around the `.first` and a blue around `.second` both have the same content but the `.second` has `overflow:hidden` thus it's outline is smaller than the `.first`

Comment: @xpy: By "how" I mean, how do you think they are of different heights? They are the same height i.e. 50px. The size will change only if you have an overflow `auto` or `scroll`, which you don't. Still, the question is very unclear as it stands. What is it that you are having a problem with? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: From MDN: "Outlines differ from borders in the following ways: Outlines do not take up space, they are drawn above the content. ..." - Which would explain why they don't add to their size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: @Abhitalks My bad, I'm looking it in Firefox, obviously you are looking it in chrome, didn't expect that big difference between the two.

Comment: How is Firefox and Chrome different? I see the same console outputs in both. And as @somethinghere pointed out, outline has no effect on the size of the element.

Comment: @epascarello I am not talking about how the outlines affect the size of an element, I am rephrasing my question right now.

Comment: You are wondering why Firefox draws the outline differently. I thought you were talke  Basically they think that the outline should wrap all of the content if it is absolutely or relatively positioned. The other browsers do not believe that. This caused me to have to do some PITA code to get around the "non bug" in their eyes. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687311

Comment: This is a known bug regarding outline in Gecko. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662902/css-outline-different-behavior-behavior-on-webkit-gecko) and [also here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687311)

Comment: Wait why are you assuming that `overflow: hidden` actually hides things by default? Without a `width` or `height` set, it responds to elements in the same way as an `overflow: initial` would, by growing to contain them.

Comment: @epascarello Actually I am wondering how can I measure the `size of the visible content` inside an element

Comment: So what do you expect the numbers to be actually?

Comment: @epascarello 200 for the `.first` and 50 for the `.second`

Comment: Problem is when you take things out of the flow, you have a different ballgame. There is no method for what you want to do. (At least I do not know of any) You would need to figure out the positions of the elements and calculate the bounding box.

Comment: `[].forEach.call(first.children, function(child) { .. get the highest bottom from child.getBoundingClientRect ... })`

Comment: @Abhitalks I thought of that too but I thing it should be recursive since the same rules will apply for the containing elements.