# ie10 stylesheet

Tags: css, styles, internet-explorer-10, conditional-comments

I'm trying to link to IE10 with an external style sheet but its not working properly.
whats happening is IE10 is using the same style sheet as the other browsers.
i have attached different stylesheets for IE 9 and 8 and those are fine.
i even tried to have a style sheet for the other browsers but IE 10 seems to think its one of the other browsers.

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie10.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: `lt` = "lower than". You are looking for `if IE 10`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what isn't IE10 proving to be standards-compliant on for you?

Comment: Disagree, dropping conditional comments from IE10 was premature.

Comment: @isherwood There is a whole lots of things that IE 10 won't show as all other than IE browsers would. The problem is that IE 10 doesn't pick IE specific style sheets.

Answer (score 12):

[if gt IE 9]  for 'greather than' 9

explained here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

BUT you should read carefully over the net ( http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/) ... **ie10 dropped conditional comments**.

Same topic here [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-ie10-for-certain-situations-like-ie-specific-css-or-ie-spec)

[no more support for conditional comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx?Redirected=true)

And to answer to : link to IE10 -->

Perhaps you can try some **jQuery** like this (nota: This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin.):

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

Or you can try the **@media -ms-high-contrast Hack** like this:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10-specific styles go here */  
}
```

or you can try the **@media Zero Hack**

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {  
    /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...THE WEBSITE im working on is www.thesda.co.za. Maybe you can have a look, the fade in sliders in the sidebar is not picking up in IE10 and the multiple backgrounds not working properly in IE8 ,so I have issues. Thanks a lot for your help guys...REALY APPRECIATE IT.

Comment: FYI `$.browser` has been deprecated from jQuery since version 1.3 and removed in jQuery 1.9. Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want lte (less than or equal) or exact match instead of lt (less than).

Comment: Lie you answered this awhile back and it sounds the most logical to me. Have you tested this method before? I have a mac so I can't test it out. `<!--[if lte IE 9]> <![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

Just finishing up on an html email (responsive). And from what I've been reading so far the solution to IE 10 isn't having an external, but using:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 

}
```

as part of the main css.

Answer (score -5):

If you're adding this to a wp theme you'll have to link it properly. Ex:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie10.css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: -1 because what is a wp theme? btw the OP didnt ask for wordpress? Also downvoted because it sums it to -3. keep SO clean.