# <!--[if lt IE 9]> Not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

i'm with a little problem.

i'm trying to use the `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` conditional to set a unique css file when open in IE, but it's not working.

i try to put on `<head>`, on `<body>`, on `footer`. i try to cange the version of my IE and nothing works. I'm getting crazy.

here's the code.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/header.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/menu-header.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/footer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/sinistro.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/laudos.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="movimentacao-ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
<title></title>
```

Help me please.

Comment: try "lte" instead of "lt"   <!--[if lte IE 9]>

Comment: tell me in which version of IE you have checked it

Comment: i try lte, lt, if IE, if lte IE 9,8,7,6.... @OzgurEffe

Comment: should that not be `css/movimentacao-ie.css`?

Comment: @SwapnilMotewar in IE7, 8 and 9

Comment: it will run only for less than 9 means 8 and less. Please check path of css file.

Comment: @Pete not realy, i change the folder to check if was the path but its not

Comment: Can you show us what styles you are trying to overwrite - a snippet of the original style and a snippet of the style from the ie stylesheet. Also you know having so many stylesheets means the browser needs to make more requests and therefore slows the loading time of the page down (more than having one big stylesheet)

Comment: for now i'm just trying to make the IE get the css (i'm trying to make the bg-color change in IE, just to know it's working), and the css files are just to organization, later i will get all together.

the mainly difference in normal and IE css is a big "background: #aac"

Comment: As @SwapnilMotewar has pointed out, this conditional statement only works for browsers, `less than` IE9 so 8, 7, 6. Check this answer out here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585703/ie10-stylesheet. Also, have you tried debugging using Firebug or the Developer console? (F12 for most).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forgot about 'css/' folder in href?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/movimentacao-ie.css" />
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work, it will target ALL versions of IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="ieOnlyStylesheet.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Not working yet... and its just with css, if i put the conditional o show a text in body it works, the path is right, the name is right...

Comment: This will not work in ALL versions of IE... the conditional comments are not longer supported on modern version of IE (10/11)

Comment: the css is just for 9 and lower