# Show Div Only in Internet Explorer (All Versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With Internet Explorer dropping the usage of conditional statements, it makes me puzzled on how one would apply elements or styles separately and only to IE. This no longer works with IE10:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<![endif]-->
```

So here is a jsfiddle of a blue and red box: http://jsfiddle.net/74yK9/1/

How would I make the blue box only appear in Internet Explorer (all versions)?

Comment: Inspect the useragent. What is the purpose of this? Do you simply not support IE in any shape form or fashion?

Comment: The more important question is, why do you need to show extra elements based on the browser?

Comment: @KevinB did you see that the leaked IE11 is using a 'Mozilla, ...like Gecko' string?

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-ie10-for-certain-situations-like-ie-specific-css-or-ie-spec - conditional compilation still works in IE10

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery, don't forget to include the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/) too:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {

    // For IE only
    $('#bluebox').show();
} else {

    // all other browsers
    $('#bluebox').hide();
}
```

Comment: @KevinB - Seems to work if you tick the "Migrate 1.1.0" checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/f4dju/

Comment: @MartinSmith It would also work if you implement the `$.browser` method yourself to look at the useragent. Just as bad.

Comment: @KevinB Your original objection was that it doesn't work though.

Comment: @MartinSmith His original objection didn't specify the "Migrate" plugin being used. The "Migrate" plugin is not something that should be used in production or planned to be used in future versions.

Comment: Right, with the current version, it won't work. you have to add extra code/files to make it work. That's like saying the jQuery library comes with a cycle widget because the plugin exists.

Comment: @MartinSmith I guess my/our point is this: `$.browser` is deprecated (**for a reason**) and not included in jQuery anymore since 1.9. The "Migrate" plugin is meant to help people migrate from older versions of jQuery to 1.9 (and above), so that they can take advantage of the newest version, yet be able to fix their code to not use deprecated/removed features. You're absolutely right that the code works if you use the "Migrate" plugin, but my objection is that you shouldn't suggest a solution that requires the "Migrate" plugin (not what it's meant for).

Comment: @Ian - Yes. I deleted my last comment as I hadn't noticed the bit in your original comment that it shouldn't be `used in production or planned to be used in future versions` so can see your point. TBH I wasn't aware that the plugin recommended in this answer was something that allowed you to carry on using deprecated features.

Comment: I didn't notice the additional link to migrate, otherwise i wouldn't have made my first comment. Was that added after the fact?

Comment: @MartinSmith No problem. I just want the answerer and OP to understand what this does and why or why not it should be used (both `$.browser` and the Migrate plugin). I should've explained better/sooner.

Comment: @KevinB Haha I feel the same way, and I don't know when it was added!

Comment: @KevinB: I hope, you can see it was answered 24 mins ago, with no edits made till now!

Comment: @Will.i.am - That doesn't mean it wasn't edited. Did you add it in as an afterthought in the 5 minute grace period? The version I saw mentioned it but Kevin's comment preceded mine by 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript, you can use conditional compilation which is only available in IE:

```
if (Function('/*@cc_on return true@*/')()) {
    // Is IE
}
```

Modified from here: [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-ie10-for-certain-situations-like-ie-specific-css-or-ie-spec)

So the way to use it is something like:

```
var isIE = false;
if (Function('/*@cc_on return true@*/')()) {
    isIE = true;
    // or
    document.documentElement.className += " isIE";
}
```

This sets a boolean in Javascript and/or also adds a `isIE` class to your `<html>` element...which will be `<html class="isIE">`. So that means you can either check the boolean `isIE` in Javacript, or style things based on the `class` like:

```
html.isIE body {
    color: #111;    /* Only applied for IE*/
}
```

This uses feature detection (kind of) and doesn't use `userAgent` sniffing. `userAgent` sniffing is an option, but isn't reliable and is deprecated/removed in modern jQuery.

A little more info on conditional compilation: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/121hztk3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx