# How to remove animations from appearing only in IE?

Tags: css

I have a keyframe animation and I believe IE 10 is the only IE browser capable of playing this animation. How could I go about removing this animation if the browser is IE and keeping it otherwise (Chrome, Safari, FireFox)?

The animation looks like this:

```
// Animations
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
.fade-in { 
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; 
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; 
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s; 
    -moz-animation-duration: .5s; 
    animation-duration: .5s;
}
.fade-in.one { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s; 
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.fade-in.two { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.2s; 
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
```

**Fiddle** 
http://jsfiddle.net/mkerny45/6yYC9/

Comment: I tried this animation in IE9 and it doesn't work.

Comment: make a fiddle with your markup and i'll show you how to detect ie10

Comment: Animation is not working out in JSFiddle, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/mkerny45/6yYC9/

Comment: ...that doesn't help at all dude.

Answer (score 1):

use conditional comments to turn the animations off. you'll need to use javascript to attach the cc's for ie10, and it should look like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->  
<script> 
// detect ie10, attach class of ie10 to html element 
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';}  
</script>  
<!-->![endif]-->  
<style>  
.ie10 .animationclass{}  
</style>
```

you can view gist here: https://gist.github.com/jalbertbowden/5174156
working demo of script here: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/ua/browsers/ie/ie10-detection-via-cc.html

Answer (score 0):

i'v find [IE10 does not read conditional comments anymore.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900331/2114572) .

so you can use jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $("html").removeClass("someClass");
}
```

or JavaScript:

```
if(Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()){
  document.documentElement.className ='';
}
```

Comment: Can I use those conditional IE tags anywhere in my html markup or only in the head?

Comment: styles must be in head tag.

Comment: ie10 understands javascript added conditional comments, but you know that because you took my answer and pasted it into yours. weak.