# Photogallery not showing in IE9 - Joomla Gantry 4

Tags: php, internet-explorer, joomla

Here is the url of my website photogallery:
 http://www.mythrottle.net/community/gallery/678-jeets/photo?albumid=135&photoid=846

I am trying hard to find out why the photo gallery is not showing in IE9 or IE10 . It works in Chrome and Firefox. I googled it out for a day and found out that the problem only comes up on Gantry 4 templates. When using the default template there are no problems. It seems that the Gantry less.css compiler is messing something up. My site is using Rocktheme Alerion and Tigra for Jomsocial styling. Anyone please help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, maybe due to something in Gantry, the width and height are being set to `0px` for IE9.

In your template folder, there should be a CSS file specifically, most likely called **ie.css**.

If not, create a new CSS file and add the following code into it:

```
.photoDisplay img {
     left: 175px; 
     top: 120px; 
     width: auto; 
     height: auto;
}
```

Then in your **index.php** in the templates folder, add in the following code in the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
        <?php  
            $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $doc->addStyleSheet(JURI::root() . "templates/rt_alerion/css/custom.css");
        ?>
<![endif]-->
```

Obviously change the path to where ever you saved the css file.

Hope this helps

Comment: OP specified that the problem is in IE9 and IE10. This fix won't work for IE10 (and can't be adjusted for it either, since IE10 doesn't support conditional comments).

Answer (score 0):

Just a long comment to the solution by @Lodder: it will not work with page caching turned on,

```
$doc->addStyleSheet
```

adds the css to a list which will later be inserted in the template where the jdoc include head is invoked;

If you want to use conditional comments (which you should if you plan on using cache) you should output the markup directly.

But since IE10 won't allow this (once again the nice guys at ms try to make our lives easier), a client-side solution like modernizr.js or [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e) will do the trick. The idea is to add a class to html or body tags with the name of the browser, so you can target it from a single stylesheet prefixing the browser-specific rules with

```
html.ie9 div.main...
```

So you can cache one page and serve to all, with the custom behaviour triggered with javascript. Additionally this will save your IE9 and 10 one extra download.  It's a nice thing to do, since they already have to deal with IE.

Also check out the boilerplate http://h5bp.com as it shows several neat tricks in the area of browser compatibility including using chromeframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer@Riccardo Zorn