# Conditional comments not working as expected

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I'm developing a site and i've seen that come contents aren't displaying correctly on IE, so i want to replace them with other IE-compatible contents.

This is what i'm using:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <div id="container">
        This is not IE, you are seeing the normal content
    </div>
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
    <div id="container">
        This is IE, you are seeing IE-compatible content
    </div>
<![endif]-->
```

The problem is that with IE version < 10, or even version 10 with compatibility mode ON i see

```
This is IE, you are seeing IE-compatible content
```

But with IE 10 with compatibility mode OFF i see

```
This is not IE, you are seeing the normal content
```

Why?

For those who wants to try it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6STq/)

Comment: Already told here:

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Answer (score 0):

There are no conditional comments in IE10 anymore

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 10 [removed support for conditional comments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx?Redirected=true), so they are treated as regular comments now.