# CSS IE10 - text-shadow spread attribute at 0px

Tags: css

Ok. So I have a blur animation on email:hover.

You may have noticed the new spread distance attribute for IE10 (only IE10 at time of posting to my knowledge). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673564(v=vs.85).aspx#text_shadows.

The problem I am having is that when spread distance is set to 0px then the text just disappears from my animation. This is probably kind of anal but shouldn't this working with 0px?

I don't want to use spread in my text shadow in my animation and IE10 is forcing me to!!!

Any idea's besides setting px so small its hard to see spread?

```
@keyframes BlurMail{
    0% {text-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px white;}
    30% {text-shadow: 0 0 7px 0px white;}
    100% {text-shadow: 0 0 0px 0px white;}
}

#email:hover {
-ms-animation-name: BlurMail; 
-ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
color: transparent;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try an IE10 specific target to add a spread to the animation so it shows up, and still use 0px in all other browsers.

[How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e#comment13686363_9900311)

This link has a lot of specific info in the comments.