# SVG animation: Isolating IE10 from other modern browsers with CSS3 media queries

Tags: internet-explorer, css, animation, svg, media-queries

I've coded a fancy loading animation in an SVG file. My problem is that Internet Explorer 10 does not support the **SVG** `<animate>` tags with the `attributeName` parameter.
Since I like some challenge, I've designed both an SVG **and** an animated GIF version for my loading animation.

Now I looking for some kind of CSS3 media query (look for the "`???????????`" within the CSS below) that would load the fallback style for modern Webkits and Gecko engines (on both desktops and mobile devices) that do support the native SVG animations, leaving the GIF fallback to both older browsers that don't support CSS3 media queries and ALL Internet Explorer browsers, from IE7 to IE10.
At least I would need it for Chrome, Safari & Safari mobile (Webkits), having it for Firefox is a nice to have.

**HTML SOURCE**

```
<div id="container" class="loadingAnim">
    <div class="loading"><span class="anim"></span></div>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS for all browsers**

```
.loadingAnim > .loading {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: .85;
}
.loadingAnim .loading .anim {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    background: white url(loadingAnim.gif) no-repeat center center;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

**CSS only for browsers that support SVG animations**

```
@media screen and (??????????? HELP ME HERE ???????????)
    .loadingAnim .loading .anim {
        background-image: url(loadingAnim.svg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

In fact, the real question is: "***Can we exclude a browser based on CSS media queries?***".

Comment: The short answer is no you can not block browsers via CSS media queries, nor should you. The longer answer is that you can if one browser supports a query that another doesn't (such as adds a new query first, or uses a prefix or the like) but that is a REALLY BAD idea. There was a IE10 specific query doing the rounds, that people would use to give hacks to IE10, but if IE11 or another version fixes the bug, it will break that browser. Developers used to target Opera by using media queries. It delayed other browsers implementing as they didn't have same bugs. Neither did later Opera versions.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but ideally you should be targeting support for features rather than browsers.

Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5) has the ability to detect support for SVG and SMIL(SVG animation). It can add a class to your html element that lets you know whether the browser supports SMIL. You can then use this to target your SVG styles to browsers that support it and give the fallback gif if they don't.

Setup the animation with gif as the default.

```
.loadingAnim > .loading {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: .85;
}

.loadingAnim .loading .anim {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    background: white url(loadingAnim.gif) no-repeat center center;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Then use the class that modernizr provides to add SVG with SMIL if supported.

```
.smil .loadingAnim .loading .anim {
    background-image: url(loadingAnim.svg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to target IE10 with media queries. And media queries aren't here for solving issues with special browser builds.
But you could - although I'd recommend to find a complete other solution - probably go for adding a special class to targeting IE10 in `<html>` and go for `.ie10 {}` specific rules in your stylesheet then, as described here by user 
[How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e#comment18903962_9900311)