# How do I make text-shadow and box-shadow use the text color on all browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, css

I'm trying to create a style for a box with a shadow that's the same color as its text. Because I have several boxes, each with a different text color, I'd like to avoid having to repeat the same color in each individual ruleset for every box.

Now, the Backgrounds and Borders module states, for [`box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) (which also applies to [`text-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow-property)):

> Where
>
> ```
> <shadow> = inset? && [ <length>{2,4} && <color>? ]
> ```
>
> The components of each `<shadow>` are interpreted as follows:
>
> - ...
> - The color is the color of the shadow. If the color is absent, the used color is taken from the ‘color’ property.<sup>1</sup>

This means that if you don't specify a shadow color on a given element, then the shadow color that's used must be taken from the text color that's computed for that element. This is similar to the behavior associated with borders without an explicit color, that dates all the way back to [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#border-color) and remains unchanged in [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-color-properties).

However, I'm aware that this was not always the case for shadows — previously (as late as 2011!) the color chosen was left up to the browser to decide in both the Text module and the B&B module. And indeed, testing in the past, I recall, showed that some browsers chose `black` and others chose `transparent` (or ignored the shadow style completely). This might even have varied between `text-shadow` and `box-shadow`. Of course, this is understandable because as mentioned, any color the browser chose would have been fine at the time.

But now that the definition has been made explicit, with the latest versions of all browsers having reflected the change as well, is there anything I can do to make the older versions follow suit? I know I can just specify the color multiple times — once for the text and once for each shadow — but like I said I'd like to avoid that if possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that in the mid-2012 WD, which is the latest as of this writing, an earlier statement in the same section contradicts the one quoted here, however the statement quoted here is the canonical one; see [this mailing list thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Feb/0204.html) and the [ED](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#the-box-shadow) where this has been fixed.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior described in CSS1 and CSS2 has been extended in Color level 3 with a [`currentColor` keyword value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentcolor), which basically means "the computed value of `color` for this element" and can be used anywhere a color value is accepted. As you might expect, this has been retconned into the `border-color` propdef as its initial value, as seen in the B&B module, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-color).

Since almost every browser that supports `box-shadow` and `text-shadow` also supports `currentColor`, you should be able to just specify that as the shadow color:

```css
text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em currentColor;
box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em currentColor;
```

This explicitly instructs the browser to use the same color as the text, and not whatever it was programmed to use otherwise, in a way [normalizing](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css) the behavior across browsers. [Interactive fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Q4Ghy)

Unfortunately, for some really stubborn browsers, like certain versions of some WebKit browsers, the problem lies not in the fact that they do not use `currentColor`, but the fact that *they do not implement `currentColor` with these properties correctly*. This means even if you do try to set the color value explicitly, it still won't work, because that's what they already do — they just aren't doing it correctly.

Specifically, Safari is known to have no support for `currentColor` whatsoever until version 4, but for reasons I cannot comprehend, Safari 5.x fails to apply the above declarations correctly, despite being able to apply something like `background-color: currentColor` just fine. I believe this is fixed in Safari 6.x and later, but since 6.x and later apply declarations without the color component correctly *anyway*, they don't even need this workaround.

Passing `currentColor` explicitly *does* work around a strange bug in Firefox that prevents it from animating to and from `text-shadow` or `box-shadow` values without a color component — in the interactive fiddle linked above, if you change either the `div:not(:hover)` rule or the `div:hover` rule to remove `currentColor` from either shadow declaration, that shadow won't animate in Firefox.

If you absolutely need to support old versions of WebKit browsers, you'll have no choice but to hardcode the desired color. But considering how frequently and rapidly those browsers update themselves anyway, you're probably better off worrying about old versions of IE instead. Note however that IE9 has no trouble supporting `box-shadow` without the color component, and likewise for IE10 with `text-shadow`, so IE does not require this workaround at all. [Shock and awe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e/9900331#9900331)

Comment: True, but this is a relatively new keyword. Is this supported by the older browsers the OP is concerned about?

Comment: @Mr Lister: It's not that new - in fact, `currentColor` was implemented by Firefox *before* `box-shadow` or `-moz-box-shadow`. The exception to "almost every browser" as stated in my answer is desktop Safari < 4 (supports `-webkit-box-shadow` but not `currentColor`), but I doubt that is widely used anymore.

Comment: @Mr Lister: So it turns out, Safari 5.x has trouble with `currentColor` despite it being nothing new. I just updated my answer with more browser compatibility findings that, admittedly, should have been there in the very beginning.