# How to make div 10% of device screen height css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am looking for is a CSS equivalent of jQuery's `$("div").css({"height":screen.height/10})`

I have heard of CSS media queries and I like them, but I don't know of anything that could even do something even close to that. I know how to use `min-height` query:

```
@media (min-height: ... /* some height */){
    div{
        height: ... /* 'some height' divided by ten */
    }
}
```

but it only gets 10% height of the browser window (not what I'm looking for!).

And I can't just simply use `height: 10%` because the div is nested in another element that has a set height in pixels.

I also can't use `height: 10vh` because the viewport's height is not at all the device screen's height (tested in Chrome and IE; If you want proof, resize the window. You'll notice that the height changes as the window's height changes)

**NOTE:**

I am asking that the div be 10% of the device screen, meaning that if the computer's monitor (the device screen) has a resolution of 1280px by 800px, then the div should be 10% of 800px, which is 80px. Also, if the window resizes, the div's height should not change, because even though the window is resizing, **it is impossible to resize the physical computer monitor or phone screen**

Comment: What do you mean by 10% full screen but not the window?

Comment: I meant 10% of the device screen not the browser window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `min-device-height` instead of `min-height`:

```
@media (min-device-height: ... /* some height of the screen*/){
    div{
        height: ... /* 'some height' divided by ten */
    }
}
```

This also applies to the other dimensional queries such as:

`min-width` -> `min-device-width`

`height` -> `device-height`

`width` -> `device-width`

for more visit [Mozilla's guide for CSS queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#Pseudo-BNF_(for_those_of_you_that_like_that_kind_of_thing)).

Comment: @Carlos Calla: No, maybe he did it so others could benefit from the answer. If you look at the Ask Question page, you'll see that there's a feature that allows you to post your own answer together with the question. Even I do it too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196773/why-is-this-non-float-margin-collapsing-with-a-float http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560018/how-do-i-make-text-shadow-and-box-shadow-use-the-text-color-on-all-browsers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css

Answer (score 18):

It's not entirely clear what you are referring to but there IS a CSS property for this.

It's the vertical height unit (vh)

Each `vh` equates to 1% of the vertical height of the screen / viewport.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srf2ojfk/)

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: red;
    height:10vh;
}
```

[**CanIUse**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) reference

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) reference

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem. I want height of device, not viewport.

Comment: I doesn't appear that way in chrome. `vh` is equivalent to javascript `window.height`; I want `screen.height`

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.innerHeight`:

```
document.getElementById([DIV ID]).style.height = (window.innerHeight / 10); // Gets window height.
window.onresize = function() { document.getElementById([DIV ID]).style.height = (window.innerHeight / 10);
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerHeight

Comment: Ignore the comment that was left earlier. You are free to answer any question you wish provided it is on-topic, even if the asker has provided an answer of their own. In fact, if you know that the asker's answer is wrong and you know the correct answer, I would strongly encourage you to post it.

Comment: You saved my life. `vh` has issues with mobile browsers. This would be perfectly what I wanted.