# Best way to detect <= IE10

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, detection

What's an up-to-date way for detecting IE?

- conditional comments don't do <strike>IE9</strike>, IE10
- modernizr feature detection doesn't help here, because the reason is external (IE bug in a mapbox map I want to embed)
- jQuery + migrate plugin: if this helps, what are the basic steps?

Yeah, I'm rather new to this. Cheers!

Comment: Do you want to detect on the client or server?

Comment: I would look at existing questions such as:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Comment: To correct your first point, IE9 *does* do conditional comments. It's only in IE10 that it stopped supporting them.

Comment: Usually in practice you don't actually want to detect IE, instead you want to detect IEs lack of a certain feature. It is usually a cleaner route to check for that feature instead of the browser, as it will also fire for other browsers which lack that feature. The core issue then is why are you checking for IE?

Comment: @Nucleon I don't know why mapbox pins are not shown in IE. They say they're aware of the bug.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use conditional comments for IE6-9 and a little custom function for IE10. For example:
HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

JS:

```
if ($('html').hasClass('ie') || (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')())){
    isIE = true;
}else{
    isIE = false;
}
```

or you can just use:

```
if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()){
    document.documentElement.className+=' ie';
}
// Then..
if($('html').hasClass('ie')){...} // to check for IE10 and below.
```

Other answers focus on specifically detecting IE10 but I thought it would be helpful to show complete detection code in one place.

Comment: Doesn't that just test for a class on the html element?

Comment: @Torr3nt - yes, the code directly above it adds the `ie` class to the `html` element if IE10 is detected. You could just as easily define a variable like I did in my first example.

Comment: On that note, can't you just use a conditional to target IE? `<!--[if IE]> <html class="ie"> <![endif]-->`, or does IE10 not support the general IE conditional either?

Comment: @Torr3nt - no, IE10 doesn't support conditional comments so you have to use an alternative.

Comment: The JS-if/else does not output anything, do you know what's wrong here? (html comments are replaced by actual code, no worry)
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('html').hasClass('ie')){ document.write("
<!-- Google Maps-Embed -->
"); }
else { document.write("
<!-- Mapbox-Embed -->
"); }
</script>

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: If I wanted to say IE 10 or less could I just change `document.documentMode===10` to `document.documentMode<=10`? I understand I could use the conditionals for under 10 but in my case, the script (polyfill) I'm using needs to fire for anything 10 and under so I might as well just do it like that if I can.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <!-- IE10 -->
    <script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE 10/)){

        var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];   
        var newLink = document.createElement('link');

        newLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
        newLink.type = 'text/css';
        newLink.href = 'css/ie10.css';

        headID.appendChild(newLink);
    } else {
       /* do something for other versions */
    }
    </script>
```