# IE10 Repaint/Redraw issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, repaint, redraw

You can see this working/breaking here: http://new.campchampions.com/parents

The issue only crops up in IE10. After the user has scrolled a little ways, the navigation becomes pinned (a class of `fixed` gets added to the `body` which effects the `hgroup.primary`(I know, I know hgroup is not a 'thing' anymore. Don't judge me.)). If you go back to the top of the page, it un-pins, goes back to normal.

In IE10, when you go back up to the top of the page, the nav elements disappear until the mouse moves up over ANY part of the yellow bar. It's driving me nuts.

I've attempted things like having JS append/alter content in various elements on scrolltop/un-pinning the navigation.

I've got a brief youtube video showing the issue: http://youtu.be/-itTC_j-9YE

Any thoughts, or ideas? That'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: seems like you fixed the issue. i checked your video, brought the site up on IE10, and didn't see the issue.

Comment: Sorry, Raylee. Another guy here in the office figure out a solution. It's not pretty and we don't know what the real problem is (assuming it's a bug). But for the users, no harm no foul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I have no solid answer for the reason behind this redraw issue, I found that an instantaneous jQuery hide/show redrew the element completely without any visible side effects.

Using a non-jQuery JS hack to add a class to the HTML element in IE10 (see [Willem de Wit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13971998/146554) to this quandry), I made sure this code only fired on IE10.

```
if($('html').hasClass('ie10')) {
  $('.primary').hide(0, function(){$(this).show()});
}
```