# Bootstrap form-control class conflicting with Knockout databind

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, internet-explorer-10

I'm experiencing this weird bug with IE10 and it doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox.

The bug is that when I use `form-control` from Bootstrap combine on a pair of parent-child `select` elements with Knockout data binding, the child `select` takes forever to refresh. But if you mouse over the child element, it refreshes right away.

Here's the JS to reproduce it.

Try browse this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/o2fqaxLh/) with IE10 and change the value in the first `select`, the second `select` will not refresh unless you wait for a long time or mouse over to the second `select`.

But if I do not use `form-control` class for `select` elements, the problem goes away like in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/o2fqaxLh/1/).

**HTML**

```
<label for="cats">Categories</label>
<select id="cats" data-bind="options: availableCats, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedCat, event: {change: populateItems}" class="xform-control"></select>
<label for="items">Items</label>
<select id="items" data-bind="options: availableItems, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedItem" class="xform-control
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var BaseVM = function () {
        var that = {};
        return that;
    };

    var TestVM = function () {
        var that = BaseVM();

        that.availableCats = ko.observableArray([{
            name: '--'
        }, {
            name: 'pork'
        }, {
            name: 'ham'
        }]);
        that.selectedCat = ko.observable(null);
        that.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);
        that.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);

        that.populateItems = function () {
            that.availableItems([]);

            if (that.selectedCat().name === 'pork') {
                that.availableItems([{
                    name: 'chop'
                }]);
            } else if (that.selectedCat().name === 'ham') {
                that.availableItems([{
                    name: 'spam'
                }]);
            }
        };

        return that;
    };

    var vm = TestVM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Comment: Works fine in IE11; maybe an incompatibility issue

Comment: @Hackerman, thanks for checking. But the enterprise users are stuck on IE10.

Comment: IE10, ouch. I feel your pain. This is a crazy IE10 repaint/redraw issue. Someone has posted a question with a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068846/ie10-repaint-redraw-issue).

Comment: I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2fqaxLh/2/) with the [solution suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18473826/1062224) from the other question. I've tested this in IE10 and it works.

Comment: @AnishPatel, thank you for sharing that solution. I think I'll use it since our users only use IE10. I'll comment on the code to make sure it'll be taken out when no longer needed. Please post as an answer so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: @RayCheng glad I could help buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is an IE10 redrawing issue.

Another person had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068846/ie10-repaint-redraw-issue).

Unfortunately, the solution is not ideal and very hacky.

You will need to add this code at the bottom of your `populateItems` function after all of your update logic:

```
$('#items').hide(0, function(){$(this).show()});
```

This will give IE10 a nudge to redraw the *select* element.

Here is your fiddle, [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/o2fqaxLh/2/) with the working solution.

Comment: I also found that toggling the child's `disabled` property also fixes the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/o2fqaxLh/3/