# IE conditional statment not working no matter what I do

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

This is incredibly frustrating, the if IE statement does not seem to work no matter what I do

I'm using IE 10

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<!--[if IE]> 
<h1>You are using Internet Explorer</h1> 
<![endif]--> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that conditional comments do not work, and are deprecated, in Internet Explorer 10.

References:

- '[Microsoft drop conditional comments in IE10](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/).'

Comment: I can only really point you to this question (among others): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Comment: @huntingbears: Don't.  Use feature detection.

Comment: I have an image aligned 400px from the left, in IE it's not far enough across, like it's starting the 400px from further back, any way around this??

Comment: Not without seeing your HTML and CSS, no.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still reaches this page, wondering why the ie targeting doesnt work. IE 10 and onward no longer support conditional comments. From the MS official website:

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5.

Please see here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

If you desperately need to target ie, you can use this jquery code to add a ie class to  and then use .ie class in your css to target ie browsers.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
 $("html").addClass("ie");
}
```