# make specific css code for IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I bind some type for my site:

```
@font-face {
font-family:WILLS;
src:url(WILLS.TTF);
}
```

In most browsers this types recognize perfectly but IE don't see this type because of ttf extensions. But the problem is that IE10+ aren't support this condition.

`<!--[if IE]>...<![endif]-->`

Is there any way to make specific css code for IE10 to change type to usuall, for example Tahoma or times and ofcourse change font-size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e)

Comment: found good decision for this issue, any css would be specific for IE9,IE10 - @media screen and (min-width:0\0) { css code for ie9,10}. And converting ttf to eot and adding url(WILLS.EOT) won't help

Comment: so  \0 is for 10 ? and i thought it would be \9 for 19

Comment: @Sevar well out of my curiosity I want to know is \0 for IE10 ?

Comment: this specific css code @media screen and (min-width:0\0) {} works only with IE10 and IE9. I was checked now in IE9,10

Comment: Why would eot not help you?

Comment: @Sevar could you please comment on the specific answers if anything suggested did not work? This makes the whole clearer to people trying to come up with suggestions!

Comment: CSS codes

For IE7 only - *

*font-family:WILLS; 

For IE8 only - _

_font-family:WILLS; 

For IE9 only - \9

font-family:WILLS\9;

For IE10 only - \0

font-family:WILLS\0;

Comment: @sg3s the suggestions about converting .ttf extension to .eot and adding url(WILLS.EOT); won't help, IE9,10 can't see this maybe because this type can't be clearly converted to eot, I don't know

Comment: @sg3s converted this font using link you provide and all works perfectly in IE9,10 , thanks for this generator, it's very useful!

Comment: @Sevar I was about to say! I just was just about to post screenshot proof that my generator answer would work out :p Don't forget to accept an answer if your question is answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look into a webfont generator. It will give you the font types you need to also support IE10 and will make css code which ensures best support cross-platform.

Font Squirrel is the most used/popular out there but there are more

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 6):

You will need to specify a EOT file for IE9+ and a TTF file for <= IE8

```
@font-face {
font-family:WILLS,
src:url(WILLS.TTF),
url(WILLS.EOT); /* IE9+ */
}
```

If you convert the TTF file to an EOT file and upload both files. IE9 and above will use the EOT file