# Complex selector don't work in last blink version :nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2){}

Tags: css, webkit, css-selectors, blink

there is strange problem: after blink update selector `.groups .group:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2){}` just stop working.
But it still works well in webkit and gecko. Any ideas how to fix it?

HTML

```
<div class="groups">
    <div class="group"></div>
    <div class="group"></div>
    <div class="group"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.groups .group{
    background-color:#000;
}
.groups .group:first-child{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.groups .group:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
.groups .group:nth-child(2):last-child{
    background-color:red;
}
.groups .group:last-child:nth-child(3){
    background-color:green;
}
.groups{
    font-size:0;
}
.groups .group{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:30px;    
}
```

You may see how it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/LAq73/1/

How it work in blink (chrome): [image: How it work in blink (chrome)]

How it work in safari (webkit): [image: How it work in safari (webkit)]

And finaly FF: [image: How it work in gecko (FF)]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Both Chrome 31.0.1650.57 and Canary 33.0.1726.0 work the same way as Gecko does, for me. What's the 'last blink version', I wonder?

Answer (score 2):

Usage of nth-last-of-type instead nth-last-child save the day.

```
.groups .group{
    background-color:#000;
}
.groups .group:first-child{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.groups .group:nth-child(2):nth-last-of-type(2),
.groups .group:nth-child(2):last-child{
    background-color:red;
}
.groups .group:last-child:nth-child(3){
    background-color:green;
}
.groups{
    height:100px;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}
.groups .group{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:30px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LAq73/3/

Comment: So Blink inexplicably has trouble with `:nth-last-child()`. Can you test this workaround with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346681/using-nth-child-and-nth-last-child-simultaneously and see if it works as well? If it does, then it's probably the same issue, and one that only affects Chrome on the Mac.

Comment: Note of course that this only works if all elements are of the same type (in this case, it's `div`) - otherwise, you'd be SOL.

Answer (score -1):

You are making it too complex.

Write:

```
.groups .group:first-child{ /*first child*/
    background-color:yellow;
}
.groups .group:nth-child(2){ /*second child*/
    background-color:red;
}
.groups .group:last-child{ /*last child*/
    background-color:green;
}
```

[**Working fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAq73/2/)