# Using :nth-child and :nth-last-child simultaneously

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I can't make `:nth-child` and `:nth-last-child` pseudo-classes work simultaneously.

Works well (highlights first 3 elements):

```
#a li:nth-child(-n+3) {
   background: #fbfcc8; 
}
```

[image: #a]

Works well (highlights last 3 elements):

```
#b li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
   background: #fbfcc8; 
}
```

[image: #b]

Doesn't work (highlights first 3 elements and last one):

```
#c li:nth-child(-n+3), #c li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
   background: #fbfcc8; 
}
```

[image: #c]

http://jsfiddle.net/8GSQ6/2/

**Update**:

In real I have more complicated HTML, so seems like it's just a bug.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the fiddle you've provided in Firefox. I see it working correctly, highlighting all but item 4. Which browser did you test with?

Comment: Same here, I am also seeing all last three items highlighted in Chrome. Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: It works in Firefox 25 and Chromium 30.

Comment: It's also working as expected in IE9.

Comment: It's weird. I'm using Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57.

Comment: No repro in my Chrome, with the exact same version. Are you on a Mac? I'm on Windows.

Comment: @all it can be reproduced in latest stable Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/8GSQ6/4/

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot reproduce it here.

Comment: Seems like bug in Blink or WebKit, sometimes it works sometimes it's not. Try to click "Run".

Comment: I've clicked it about 20 times, still no repro. If you're on a Mac, because it looks a lot like it, then it's probably an issue with Chrome on the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a bug in Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57 for Mac. Firefox, Safari and latest Google Chrome works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    #c1 li:nth-child(-n+3), #c1 li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
       background: #fbfcc8; 
    }
```

This works for me..

Change id to `c1`.

Comment: If i use only `c` it doesn't work. If i try something like `c1` it works.

Comment: OK, now that's just bizarre. What browser, version and OS are you using?

Comment: i am using `chrome 31.0.1650.57` and `mac osx 10.9`.

Comment: Then it's probably an issue with Chrome on the Mac, because the OP appears to be on a Mac as well and his Chrome version is the same. I cannot reproduce it on Windows.