# How to detect internet explorer version in wordpress and add code with if statement?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, browser-detection

I want to detect Internet Explorer version and change some css with if statement to debuging.
and How to detect it in by using wordpress?

and how to code `if(//IE version whatever){ //to code here}`

any idea?

Comment: Did you try this? http://wordpress.org/plugins/php-browser-detection/

Comment: Why not use `<!--[if lt IE 7]> ...somecode... <![endif]-->` in your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to detect IE browser via wordpress, instead you can make use of [**`conditional comments`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX) in your script.  Which get executed only in IE.  Using this you can have a separate CSS for IE browsers.

An example,

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Upvoted, but bear in mind that IE10 doesn't implement conditional comments (this may, or may not, be a problem since it's, allegedly, pretty good at implementing CSS).

Comment: Will this really works? :O

Comment: Its IE. Its still a problem.

Comment: @Mr.beginner Yes I have used it,  however as David Thomas mentioned [Conditional comments are no longer supported in IE10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: what to code if IE 10 or greater than 10 ?

Comment: @Mr.beginner then you need to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13971998/1671639) incase if you're interested in `modernizr` then move on to feature detection.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for your comment I have add the link too, glad to receive an upvote especially from you

Comment: after putting my this code `<style type="text/css">
<?php if(is_ie() && get_browser_version() >= 10) :?>
  #sms-cont {
   
   height:317px !important;
  }
  <?php endif; ?>
 </style>` the site is not loading completly. :(

Comment: @Mr.beginner This isn't what I told.  Try my approach `<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css"> #sms-cont { height:317px !important; }</style>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43786/discussion-between-mr-beginner-and-praveen-jeganathan)

Comment: You're very welcome. But why "especially from [me]"? I've got a pretty good rep, but ain't nothing special (I've just had a lot of free time to kill over the past couple years...) :)

Comment: @DavidThomas you're one among [my favorites](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1671639/praveen-jeganathan) who care to answer others.  
I used to add users to the list when I cross people like you.  I haven't start to earn big, once I reach that level I will help out as you [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/david-thomas) Thats why I mentioned you're special :)