# Why is IE specific stylesheet is being ignored

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following stylesheet inside the `HEAD` piece of my website:

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]-->
```

I am running IE version 10 but for some reason it is reading the non IE stylesheet. Any idea how to fix it? Do I have to be specific in the IE condition?

I looked in the developer tool, and only the NON IE version has been loaded...

Ended up using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.clipboardData)
     alert("You are using IE!");
else
     alert("NON IE");
</script>
```

Comment: No questions on IE. They can do what they want or ignore what they want. That's the sad reality.

Comment: @Esser: Don't you just hate free will? Look at Chrome, WebKit and Blink, adding features as and when they want then trying to shoehorn them into the standards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX):

> As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer
>   supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide
>   effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't
>   supported by the browser.

[and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change
>   can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or
>   pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet
>   Explorer.

Comment: So how do I rewrite my code to make sure for ANY version of IE it takes the `_ie` css and anything else use the standard css file?

Comment: This JavaScript related question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Comment: I updated my question with a solution I am using... Is it sufficient enough?

Comment: Looks like a potential, albeit not widely used, solution. If it works for you then it's fine.

Comment: You should not need to give IE a different stylesheet. If it works in Chrome & firefox it should work in IE, unless you are using vendor specific prefixes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Only allow the IE style sheet within the conditional comments for IE.  Your regular style sheet does not need the conditional comments.  It should read as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />

<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: It does, otherwise IE will try and read the regular style sheet which is not what the OP wants. The whole point of the question is to try and prevent it from ever reading it altogether regardless of version.

Comment: I looked in the developer console, and only the NON IE version is loaded... weird