# CSS conditional problems all IE vs the other browsers

Tags: css, conditional-statements

How to write the sintax on the css property like:

```
.example{
    /*all the browsers except IE*/
    font-size:100%;
    /*that's on all the IE syntax I need to add like a condition*/
    font-size:200%
}
```

That's a simple code I know, that's only to test it, but not on the html, on each property in a class, id or tag on the css.

In ie6 it's:

```
#test{ _color: blue}
```

in ie6 and ie7:

```
#test{ *color: blue}
```

ie6, ie7 and ie8:

```
#test{ *color: blue\9}
```

But how to difference between all IE and the other browsers?

Anyone can help?

Comment: The first question is **why** do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I have rules on my css style that don't have any type of compatibility with internet explorer? and I need to change it... that's why I want to do this

Comment: What rules could they be?

Comment: specify the font-size on seventeen class and id's, and maybe more rules but it's important to specify font-size now

Comment: Are you using a reset.css or normalize.css? That would be the way to go. http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: I'm not using any of these, only pure css, I thougt that they aren't conditional stylesheets, they are css hacks

Comment: Not they aren't. They're pure CSS stylesheets, they just set everything to the same in all browsers.

Comment: ohm, really? on all versions?? uouu I'm gonna check it

Answer (score 1):

Use `conditional stylesheets`

Target IE 6 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Target ALL VERSIONS of IE less than IE10

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Since IE10 ignores conditional comments you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e).

Learn more about it [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

Comment: Doesn't IE10+ ignore conditional comments?

Comment: So, @Chankey Pathak, I test it but my coworker and I talk about it, and we thougt it would be better to change it on the same css

Comment: @Paulie_D: What's the issue then? If the user is using IE10 then he don't need the checks for IE6,IE7 etc.

Comment: But he said he want to target **ALL** versions of IE and your No.3 won't do that...it's target IE9 and below which is not the same thing.

Comment: Because I like to use the conditional stylesheets with different css, thougt it would be better than css hacks, but my coworker likes to add css hacks than the conditional stylesheets on different css files :/

Comment: @jvillegas: There are 3 possible ways. Read this: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer