# How can I get conditional statements working for IE10?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I need to include a js file on all browsers (IE less than 11).

I have this in my header

```
<!--[if lt IE 11]><!-->
    <script>
        console.log('shouldnt see this on ie less than 11.');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/nothinglikeit/js/ie.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Funny enough, this works on IE9, but it DOESN'T work on ie10? Why is that?

From what I've read, IE10 ignores conditional statements, however I do need to include it regardless, is there a way I can do this with conditional statements?

Comment: What is in your `ie.js` that you want excluded from IE10? If it's because a specific feature is unsupported then use feature-detection instead of browser-detection.

Comment: First search result https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx (Conditional comments are no longer supported)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e)

Comment: @ben dam you beat me to it LOL

Comment: @Ben I did say that in my post, I'm asking if you can do it another way.

Comment: @dai I don't want to include libraries on a browser, just to then check with js if it supports it or not. I'd rather conditionally include the libraries.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins You **don't need** to use any additional libraries (like Modernizr), you can do the checks with exactly 3 lines of JavaScript.

Comment: @Dai I think you've misunderstood. Say I have an animation library I don't want to included on IE10, purely because it's another resource it has to load. I would have to do this check with js, then include the actual file if I want to or not. I'd much rather just do this with conditional statements, but obviously it doesn't sound like this is possible.