# Purpose of *:before, *:after rule without content property

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

From what I understand, `:before` and `:after` inserts content before or after the indicated target.  I'm not really sure what would be the purpose of this CSS snippet?

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: It adds to everything border-box so the width of the element takes into consideration padding and border. In this context i guess you took it from a css reset right ?

Comment: With that code in the width you specify to elements padding and border is included as well.

Comment: @PatsyIssa But it makes no sense here. the * adds this to all elements. So there is no need to :before or :after

Comment: @Xatenev True. I can only see the option that the writer wanted to *really* make sure the style is applied to everything (even though only the firt selector was needed).

Comment: Before and after don't inherit box-sizing from the parent

Comment: @PatsyIssa you should make an answer of your comments :)

Comment: @GCyrillus It's a trivial question and it already has 3 answers that state the same thing, no point ^^.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That applies border-box sizing to all elements as well as any `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements that they may generate. The `*:before, *:after` portion means the respective pseudo-elements of *any* element.

Once you create specific `:before`/`:after` rules later in your stylesheet, this declaration will apply automatically to all of those pseudo-elements, so you don't have to repeat it in every single one of your pseudo-element rules. In other words, the cascade works exactly the same way for pseudo-elements as it does with actual elements: when you have separate rules matching the same thing, as long as they match, they will all be applied.

Note that in order for an element to actually generate a `:before` or `:after`, its `content` must be something other than `none`. By itself, the CSS that you have given will not cause every element to automatically generate both pseudo-elements; it just ensures the browser will use border-box sizing if it does need to render any of them. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) for how generated content works.

For example, the following CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:after {
    content: "hello";
}
```

results in a `div`'s `:after` pseudo-element having border-box sizing. No other elements generate `:after` pseudo-elements, but should more CSS rules be introduced they will all have the same box-sizing from the universal rule.

Note also that `box-sizing: border-box` without the `-moz-` prefix should appear in the given CSS so other browsers will apply the same box sizing as well. The `-moz-` prefix is used by Firefox up to version 28 (the just-released version 29 ships with unprefixed `box-sizing`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828926/firefox-4-ignoring-box-sizing/5829224#5829224).

Answer (score 0):

It applies to all the elements with all the pseudo elements (:before, :after), and it makes them use `border-box` box sizing.

For more information about `box-sizing` check here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

> The `border-box` value makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box.

Answer (score -2):

`*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

This is for not to repeat in all places where you use `:after` and `:before`.
It automatically adds to all `:after` and `:before`.