# Universal selector * and pseudo elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Does the universal selector `*` affect pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after`?

Let me use an example:

When doing this:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

...doesn't the above declaration automatically include/affect pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` as well?

Or, in order to affect pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after`, one has to declare this?

```
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Does this make sense?

---

I have always used just `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` and never have had any issues with pseudo elements whatsoever. But I see many tutorials doing `*, *:before, *:after` but they never really explain why they include `*:before, *:after` in the declaration.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, the universal selector `*` does not affect pseudo-elements (except indirectly via [inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content), as pseudo-elements are typically generated as children of actual elements).

The universal selector, like other named element selectors such as `p` and `div`, is a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors):

> A *simple selector* is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

A simple selector, and by extension any complex selector, targets only actual elements.

Although pseudo-elements (which are *not* the same thing as pseudo-classes mentioned above) can appear in selector notation alongside simple selectors, pseudo-elements are completely separate from simple selectors as they [represent abstractions of the DOM that are separate from actual elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements), and therefore both represent different things. You cannot match a pseudo-element using a simple selector, nor can you apply styles to an actual element in a CSS rule with a pseudo-element in its selector.

So, in order to match `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements of any element, yes, one will need to include `*:before, *:after` in the selector. Having just `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` will not affect them since `box-sizing` is not normally inherited, and as a result, they will retain the default `box-sizing: content-box`.

One possible reason why you might never have had any issues with pseudo-elements is that they're displayed inline by default, as `box-sizing` has no effect on inline elements whatsoever.

Some notes:

- As with any other chain of simple selectors, if `*` is not the only component then you can leave it out, which means `*, :before, :after` is equivalent to `*, *:before, *:after`. That being said, the `*` is usually included for the sake of clarity — most authors are used to leaving the `*` out when writing ID and class selectors, but not pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements, so the notation may seem strange and even wrong to them (when it is in fact perfectly valid).
- The current Selectors specification that I link to above represents pseudo-elements with double colons. This is a new notation introduced in the current spec to distinguish pseudo-elements from pseudo-classes, but most `box-sizing` resets use the single colon notation to accommodate IE8, which supports `box-sizing` but not the double colon notation.
- Although `*:before, *:after` applies styles to the respective pseudo-elements of *any* element, which includes `html`, `head` and `body`, the pseudo-elements will not actually be generated until you apply the `content` property. You do not have to worry about any performance issues as there are none. For a detailed explanation, see my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542579/purpose-of-before-after-css-snippet).

Comment: does `:before: content:"Read this: ";` place content before every element? also `:before: content:"Read this: ";` places content before `html` and `body` as well

Comment: @Pilot: Yes, every element, including `html`, `head` and `body`.

Comment: shouldnt we see three (html, head, body) time `"Read this:"` here in http://jsfiddle.net/s7LAN/?

Comment: @Pilot: `head` is usually set to `display: none` by browsers because there's no reason to display it normally, so you won't see its generated content.

Comment: @BoltClock, this is the answer I was looking for. Did not know that one could leave out the "*" in `*, :before, :after`. Thank you very much for such detailed but clear explanation.

Comment: @Pilot, if you add `head { display:block; }` you'll see three `Read this -`: http://jsfiddle.net/s7LAN/1/

Comment: Wow, the other question is such an exact duplicate. If only I had seen this earlier :(

Comment: @BoltClock Can I ask whether the `*` is necessary at all for a pseudo element in the reset style? i.e. `:before{...}` vs `*:before{...}`.

Comment: @Pangloss: See the first note.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, got it now, such a great answer as always, thank you. I wish I could upvote it 10 times.

Answer (score 10):

I can only cite from the [**specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector):

> The universal selector, written "*", matches the name of any element type. It matches any single element in the document tree.

Element types are for example `span` and `div`.

Since pseudo elements don't have an "element type" and are not part of the document tree, it looks like the answer is *no*, it does not include pseudo elements.

However, since pseudo elements inherit the CSS properties from their "parent" (at least the ones that are inheritable) and the universal selector also affects the parent, it *indirectly* affects the pseudo elements.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PLpZF/)

- the color is inherited
- the border style is not and the `::before` element doesn't have a border

Comment: +1 to your answer. If I could select more than one answer I'd choose yours as well. Gave you an upvote. Thanks! :]