# How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to use flexbox to vertically align some content inside an `<li>` but not having great success.

I've checked online and many of the tutorials actually use a wrapper div which gets the `align-items:center` from the flex settings on the parent, but I'm wondering is it possible to cut out this additional element?

I've opted to use flexbox in this instance as the list item height will be a dynamic `%`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is the text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 842):

Instead of using **`align-self: center`** use **`align-items: center`**.

There's no need to change `flex-direction` or use `text-align`.

Here's your code, with one adjustment, to make it all work:

```css
ul {
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-self: center;    <---- REMOVE */
  align-items: center;   /* <---- NEW    */
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

The [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) property applies to *flex items*. Except your `li` is not a flex item because its parent – the `ul` – does not have `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` applied.

Therefore, the `ul` is not a flex container, the `li` is not a flex item, and `align-self` has no effect.

The [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) property is similar to `align-self`, except it applies to *flex containers*.

Since the `li` is a flex container, `align-items` can be used to vertically center the child elements.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-self: center; */
  align-items: center;
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is the text</li>
</ul>
```

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORQELv)

---

***Technically, here's how `align-items` and `align-self` work...***

The `align-items` property (on the container) sets the default value of `align-self` (on the items). Therefore, `align-items: center` means all flex items will be set to `align-self: center`.

But you can override this default by adjusting the `align-self` on individual items.

For example, you may want equal height columns, so the container is set to `align-items: stretch`. However, one item must be pinned to the top, so it is set to `align-self: flex-start`.

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33034660/3597276)

---

***How is the text a flex item?***

Some people may be wondering how a run of text...

```
<li>This is the text</li>
```

is a child element of the `li`.

The reason is that text that is not explicitly wrapped by an inline-level element is algorithmically wrapped by an inline box. This makes it an *anonymous inline element* and child of the parent.

*From the CSS spec:*

> [**9.2.2.1 Anonymous inline
> boxes**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous)
>
> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element
> must be treated as an anonymous inline element.

The flexbox specification provides for similar behavior.

> [**4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each
> contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex
> container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

Hence, the text in the `li` is a flex item.

Comment: I like `align-items: baseline`. Good for different heights coming from different unicode chars etc.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and linking to the concept of Anonymous inline boxes... really helps clarify why some effects you can achieve by trial and error work the way they do.

Comment: don't forget to remove any `margin: 0px;`

Answer (score 89):

The best move is to just **nest a flexbox inside of a flexbox**. All you have to do is give the child `align-items: center`. This will vertically align the text inside of its parent.

```css
// Assuming a horizontally centered row of items for the parent but it doesn't have to be
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: If you want a perfect centered text. `text-align:center` doesn't work alone. Use `align-items: center` with it.

Comment: I guess if you give `align-items: center` to the parent having `display: flex` then it automatically gets applied to all it's child elements and so do not have to explicitly declare `align-items: center` for every child

Comment: @ChandraAgarwala - that's true but you also need to add another `display: flex; align-items: center;` for each child if you want to vertically center the contents of each child.

Answer (score 57):

The most voted answer is for solving **this specific problem** posted by OP, where the content (text) was being wrapped inside an `inline-block` element. Some cases may be about **centering a normal element vertically inside a container**, which also applied in my case, so for that all you need is:

```css
align-self: center;
```

Answer (score 41):

**I** will not write the answer because many people have already given the correct one. However, I want to **show you a useful tool** that can save you from such problems in the future.

In your browser's Dev Tools, you need to inspect an element with `display: flex` and click the icon shown in the screenshot.

[image]

You will then be presented with the option to select some properties for `display: flex` so you can easily check all options quickly, without knowing what you can use.

Comment: This is really useful, just as a note, it does not seem to be in firefox but in chrome.

Comment: This is the most useful answer I've ever seen on SO!

Comment: There were probably more useful answers, but thank you!

Answer (score 13):

**RESULT**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>This is the text</li>
  <li>This is another text</li>
  <li>This is another another text</li>
</ul>
```

---

Use `align-items` instead of `align-self` and I also added `flex-direction` to `column`.

**CSS**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;  /* <--- I added this */
  align-items: center;   /* <--- Change here */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: silver;
}

.list li {  
  background: gold;
  height: 20%; 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Set the display in `li` as flex and set `align-items` to `center`.

```
li {
  display: flex;

  /* Align items vertically */
  align-items: center;

  /* Align items horizontally */
  justify-content: center;

}
```

I, personally, would also target pseudo elements and use `border-box`
([Universal selector * and pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794545/universal-selector-and-pseudo-elements))

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `display: flex` you can control the vertical alignment of HTML elements.

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Vertical */
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontal */
  border:2px solid black;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

`Align-self` does not align the items inside the li. Instead it aligns the li as a whole.

Using `align-items` would aling the text inside the li.
Check out this code. It works.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is the text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
}

li {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: silver;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is the text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's depend on your li height just call one more thing line height

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;line-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is the text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: khaki;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child item-1">English</div>
  <div class="flex-child item-2"> English</div>
  <div class="flex-child item-3"> English</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is the text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful... add comments or an explanation of what you did, and why it works.

Answer (score -7):

You could change the `ul` and `li` displays to `table` and `table-cell`. Then, `vertical-align` would work for you:

```css
ul {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: silver;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pckvK

Comment: Works well until you add another list item in there.

Comment: you've switched out the height to be on the ul instead of the li? each li height will be dynamic so this isnt something I could use im afraid

Comment: @LcSalazar You wouldn't typically use a list if you only intended to have one item. That's what divs are for.

Comment: True again... But I'm not saying this is the perfect scenario. I've just posted a solution that answers the question as it is. I hope this information might come handy to someone else that reads it and has another scenario...

Comment: Also... the `display:table` / `display:table-cell` technique is usefull for most element's hierarchy... So, I agree it is not to be chosen as the correct answer, but I hope it helps someone.