# How to vertically center the contents of a flexbox item

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I'm trying to center the CONTENTS of a flexbox item while using `justify-content:stretch;` It appears that the old trick of using `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;` doesn't work in this situation. What does?

```
.flex-container {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:stretch;
}
.flex-item {
    align-self:stretch;
}

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">I want to be vertically centered! But I'm not.</div>
</div>
```

**BEFORE YOU ANSWER:** There seems to be a lot confusion about what I'm asking. I'm trying to center the **CONTENTS** of the flex-item. With `justify-content:stretch`, the height of the item will stretch to the full height of the container, but **the contents** of the item floats to the top (at least in Chrome).

"A picture is worth a thousand words." (A) is what I've already got. (B) is what I want.
[image]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It can be achieved by `display`ing each flex item as a `flex` container and then aligning the contents vertically by `align-items` property, as follows:

```css
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  height: 200px; /* for demo */
}

.flex-item {
  align-self:stretch;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: gold; /* for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      I want to be vertically centered!
      <s>But I'm not.</s>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a side-note, if you omit the `align-items:center;` declaration of the `.flex-container` you can safely remove `align-self:stretch;` from flex items as well.

Comment: I'm seeing the contents top-aligned in mobile safari. Is that a known issue?

Comment: @SDP Make sure you have included `-webkit-` prefix as well. The new syntax of flexbox is supported in iOS Safari 7.1-8.1 but only with  `-webkit-` prefix, i,e, `display: -webkit-flex;` and `-webkit-align-items: center;`. For older versions, you have to use the [old flexbox syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/) including `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: `stretch` is not a valid value for `justify-content`. Valid values are `flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around`

Comment: By the way: The reason why this works is, that the text contained inside the `.flex-item` is considered an “anonymous inline box”. – I am not making this up, [see the W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous) and this [cool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049392/444255)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am interpreting your request correctly, but I think you are trying to use "justify-content:stretch;" when you should be using flex-grow.

Im my sample I used flex:1 auto; which is just shorthand to set a couple of flex properties.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">I'm top dog!
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-center">
        I want to be vertically centered! And I am!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:5px;
}
.flex-container {
    border: 1px solid;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    height: 100px;
}
.flex-item {
    flex: 1 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.flex-center {
    align-items: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p28tjskq/

Flex property:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0):

The text of a div-box is an anonymous inline-node. If you want to center a text in your box, you can use:

```
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
```

Make sure, that no `align-self` will destroy your results.

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:5px;
}
.flex-container {
    border: 1px solid;
    display:flex;

    height: 200px;
}
.flex-item {
    flex: 1 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    align-self:stretch;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.flex-center {
    align-items: center;
}
.flex-center div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">I'm top dog!
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-center">
        I want to be vertically centered! And I am!    
        <div style="align-self:start;">
          I want to be vertically centered too! But align-self broke it!
        </div>
        <span style="align-self:middle; color:red;">Hallo. I am a centered text. </span>
    </div>
</div>
```