# How to align text to the bottom of a flex-basis item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to align text on the `.second` paragraph to be bottom-aligned. I have to set `margin-top: auto` to align the whole element to the bottom, but the text still aligns to the top of that element, and I need a space above `.second`. `flex-basis` provides extra space and the `min-height` that I needed without having a fixed margin.

How to vertically align text inside a flex-basis item?

```css
.column{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1{
  flex-basis: 70px;
}

.second{
  flex-basis: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <h1>Subscribe</h1>
    <p class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae velit qui natus iure quisquam consequatur debitis saepe sint ex at.</p>
    <p class="second"> eusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311541/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `display: flex` and `align-items: flex-end` to the `.second` *div*:

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  flex-basis: 70px;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-basis: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <h1>Subscribe</h1>
  <p class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae velit qui natus iure quisquam consequatur debitis saepe sint ex at.</p>
  <p class="second"> eusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make it also a flex container and use `align-items: flex-end` to push content to the bottom.

Stack snippet

```css
.column{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1{
  flex-basis: 70px;
}

.second{
  flex-basis: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: auto;

  display: flex;                    /*  added  */
  align-items: flex-end;            /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <h1>Subscribe</h1>
    <p class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae velit qui natus iure quisquam consequatur debitis saepe sint ex at.</p>
    <p class="second"> eusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```