# Flexbox parent align-items overriding child justify-content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following code, if I comment out the `align-items` line in flex-column, the background is gray and space exists between the icons. If I uncomment the `align-items`, the background is blue and the icons are centered together.

I've thought of `align-items` and `justify-content` as orthogonal to each other - why is `align-items` affecting a flexbox spacing issue in a child flexbox container? Doesn't the width start at 100%?

I would assume it would only manage its direct children. Further, the entire area is blue when `align-items` is active, shouldn't I at least see the background of the icons as gray?

```css
.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-row {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flex-column">
      <div>Some Content0</div>
      <div>Some Content1</div>
      <div class="flex-row" style='border: solid;'>
        <img src="update.svg" style="max-width: 20px;">
        <img src="update.svg" style="max-width: 20px;">
      </div>
      <div>Some Content2</div>
      <div>Some Content3</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent flex container is set to column-direction. This means that the main axis is vertical and the cross axis is horizontal.

The `align-items` property works only along the cross axis.

So when you set the container to:

```
align-items: center
```

... the child (`.flex-row`) is horizontally centered.

Basically, all free space on either side of the flex item is consumed, causing the item to be centered.

The parent's background color (blue) is displayed because the child's background color (gray) has been squeezed to the center, and lies behind the images.

---

When you disable `align-items: center` on the parent, the default `stretch` value is restored on the child.

The child (`.flex-row`) is, unlike its parent, a row-direction container. So the main axis is horizontal and the cross axis is perpendicular.

The `justify-content` property works only along the main axis. So in this case, it works in the same direction as `align-items` on the parent.

With `justify-content: space-between` on the child container and `align-items: stretch` on the parent container, the images and the child's gray background color have access to the full length of the container.

---

> Doesn't the width start at 100%?

Often, yes. But in any case, you've overridden full-length with centering.

Maybe you're thinking that only the content (the images) should be centered and not the flex items. That's not exactly how it works. There are three independent levels in a flex container:

- the container
- the items
- the content

Here's a more complete explanation (it focuses on Grid but the concepts apply to flex, as well):

- [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)

---

Learn more about flex alignment along the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment along the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Comment: There were two concepts I thought I understood, but didn't. The first was content vs. the item. The second was not realizing the main axis definition was dependent on the direction. After understanding this, a lot of articles suddenly make more sense. I made a few changes for future viewers, I added some block items to show that I was trying to vertically align all items, and then expand the icons. To get it working, I set the parent container to justify-content instead of align-items as you mentioned. The content was shifted left, so I used text-align: centered on the parent container.

Comment: To really grasp the concepts discussed in my answer, see the link references I posted. They should cover 70% of what you need to know. For another 20%, see my answers [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19026884/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311541/3597276). And for everything else see the top answers [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b?tab=answers&sort=votes). Then you're an expert :-) Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

On a *flex column* container the `align-items` affect the cross axis (horizontal), and with its default value `stretch`, makes its flex item's fill its width (be 100% wide).

When you change that to `center`, it will be the items width that control whether they *fill* its parent's width, and since yours doesn't, they will, as you told them to (`align-items: center`), center nicely.