# CSS text-overflow ellipsis not working in Grid / Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

I am not able to get `text-overflow` ellipsis to work in a CSS grid. The text is truncated but the ellipsis dots don't show up.  Here is my CSS:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 15fr
}

.gridItem {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(50px + 2vw);
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridItem">Why no ellipsis on this div?</div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: display:flex; doesn't mix with ellipsis, it is supposed to hold tags not plain text. Might be the reason why ellipsis is not triggered. flex is also a grid system :(

Comment: Wrap content inside flex item with an element (`<span>` probably works best for this[.](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/text-overflow-ellipsis-doesnt-work)) Set the item itself to, `min-width: 0;` (And, also, follow all other rules that make ellipsis work in a regular div.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make the ellipsis work you need to target the *text* not the *container*.

In your code, you are setting the ellipsis on the flex container (a grid item):

```
.gridItem {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    height: calc(50px + 2vw);
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

The child of the container is the text. Except you can't apply any CSS directly to the text because it's an *anonymous flex item* (i.e., a flex item with no defined tags around it). So you need to wrap the text into an element and then apply the ellipsis code.

From this:

```
<div class="gridItem">Why no ellipsis on this div?</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="gridItem"><span>Why no ellipsis on this div?</span></div>
```

Then you have to contend with the *minimum sizing algorithm* of flex items. This rule, set by default, states that a flex item cannot be smaller than its content along the main axis. The solution to this problem is to set the flex item to `min-width: 0`, which overrides the default `min-width: auto`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 15fr;
}

.gridItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(50px + 2vw);
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width: 0;
}

.gridItem > span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridItem"><span>Why no ellipsis on this div?</span></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
  <div class="gridItem"></div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBVQwX)

These posts provide more detailed explanations:

- [understanding the flex minimum sizing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/3597276)
- [understand anonymous flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049392/3597276)

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be that `.gridItem` has `display: flex;` styling on it, if you take that off it works. If you need to have `display: flex;` on your grid items then this article may be helpful: https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/