# Right-align a flex item and vertically center its content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to set right box position right using flex and also colorful text vertically centered in the box?

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}
.box .left-box {
  width: 30%;
}
.box .right-box {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #3e9388;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left-box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</div>
  <div class="right-box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested flex container so you can apply flex alignment properties to the text.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  
  /* new */
  justify-content: space-between; /* for right-alignment */
}
.box .left-box {
  width: 30%;
}
.box .right-box {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #3e9388;
  
  /* new */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left-box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</div>
  <div class="right-box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

More details here:

- [How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311541/3597276)
- [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19026884/3597276)

Comment: I am probably wrong but I think we need to also right align the green box. (not the downvoter)

Comment: I think you're correct. The original question was not entirely clear. I edited the q for clarity (and assumed intent) and updated my answer. OP can correct me if I'm wrong. @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 3):

See below fiddle if you wanted the green box to be position to the right, also:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box .left-box {
  width: 30%;
}
.box .right-box {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #3e9388;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4z0aqvxk/4/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.
Never hesitate to use `flex` inside `flex`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box .left-box {
  width: 30%;
}
.box .right-box {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #3e9388;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left-box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</div>
  <div class="right-box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first add "flex-direction: row"  to the box  so each element will be align horizontaly

Then you can play with "justify-content: center" and "align-items" attribut

Comment: This could be improved by providing examples in a code snippet