# How to vertically center an unordered list with display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey people I'm trying to vertically center an ul inside a flex div.
right now its center only for the horizontal.

[image]

how can I center it vertically?

```css
#skills {
  background-color: #262626;
  height: 100px;
  /* padding: 50px 0 50px 0; */
}
#skills ul {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#skills ul li {
  font-size: 60px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.fab,
.fas {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills">
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fab fa-java"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
        <li><i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-js-square"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-node"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-angular"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-aws"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-git"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-database"></i></li>
    </ul>  
</section>
```

Comment: Check the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311541/how-to-vertically-align-text-inside-a-flexbox

Comment: @JulianEspinosa Please do not answer in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have successfully centered the list items inside the `ul`.

```
#skills ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

You just haven't centered the `ul` inside the `section`. So add this to your code:

```
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
#skills {
  background-color: #262626;
  height: 100px;
  /* padding: 50px 0 50px 0; */
  /* new */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#skills ul {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#skills ul li {
  font-size: 60px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.fab,
.fas {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fab fa-java"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-js-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-node"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-angular"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-aws"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fab fa-git"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-database"></i></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```