# align text of flex item to center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with 3 flex items

the text of the two outer items should be at the center point of each item
so far the text appears on the top of

using `align-items: center;`
recommended in [How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049392/12753324)
on the container just squished the divs to one line, ignoring the heigth of the container.

how to center the text at the center of each div ?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}


.file_upload-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 200px;

    /*align-items: center;*/
    justify-content: center;
}


.drop-zone_main {
    color: #cccccc;
    border: 4px dashed #009578;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.upload_spacer {
    background-color: #00ffb7;
    flex-basis: 200px;
}

.drop-zone_second {
    color: #cccccc;
    border: 4px dashed #009578;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-basis: 300px;
}

input {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="file_upload-container">

      <div class="drop-zone_main">Drop MainFile here or click to upload</div>

      <input class="input_main" type="file" name="upload_mainfile">

      <div class="upload_spacer"></div>

      <div class="drop-zone_second">Drop second file here or click to upload</div>

      <input class="input_second" type="file" name="upload_secondfile">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your input in a `div`, so it gets aligned with its siblings, and use `display: flex` to align the inner content:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}


.file_upload-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 200px;

    /*align-items: center;*/
    justify-content: center;
}


.drop-zone_main {
    color: #cccccc;
    border: 4px dashed #009578;
    border-radius: 10px;
   
}

.upload_spacer {
    background-color: #00ffb7;
    flex-basis: 200px;
}

.drop-zone_second {
    color: #cccccc;
    border: 4px dashed #009578;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-basis: 300px;
}

.input-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="file_upload-container">

  <div class="drop-zone_main">Drop MainFile here or click to upload</div>
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <input class="input_main" type="file" name="upload_mainfile">
  </div>
  <div class="upload_spacer"></div>

  <div class="drop-zone_second">Drop second file here or click to upload</div>
  <div class="input-wrap">
  <input class="input_second" type="file" name="upload_secondfile">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have forgot to mention that the input is hidden, added it to my question

Comment: just change the display: none to display: flex when you need to show it, if not, i don't get the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the `css` rules :

```
.drop-zone_main {
    color: #cccccc;
    border: 4px dashed #009578;
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}



.drop-zone_second {
    color: #cccccc;
    border: 4px dashed #009578;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-basis: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: using `display: flex` on the child elements does not look technically correct

Comment: .@real_hagrid `.drop-zone_main` and `.drop-zone_second` are not only children but also parents of text node inside them. I checked from my side and it works ;-)