# How to place responsive text inside of a cell

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a simple Tic Tac Toe board I am working on, the only problem is the X and the O.
As you can see, to center the text I have to use font-size, and when I make the board smaller (it's responsive) the text stays the same size.
Is there a way to make this responsive and still remain centered? The board also breaks at certain pixel sizes.

```css
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  /* Set a transparent border */
  font-size: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cellContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 4px solid #000;
  /* Set an outline for the container */
}

#gameContainer {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Permanent Marker", cursive;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Itim&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="gameContainer">
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div id="cellContainer">
    <div cellIndex="0" class="cell">X</div>
    <div cellIndex="1" class="cell">O</div>
    <div cellIndex="2" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="3" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="4" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="5" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="6" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="7" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="8" class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="statusText"></h2>
  <button id="restartBtn">Restart</button>
</div>
```

I tried using media queries but I am looking for a responsive result, because the board will get slightly smaller and the text wont be centered.

Comment: Perhaps you want to set the `font-size` to `vw` or `vh`.

Comment: "to center the text I have to use font-size".  There are many ways to center text other than by font size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311541/how-to-vertically-align-text-inside-a-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

CSSGrid and `aspect-ratio` for the layout.

Then use `vw` units for the font size.

```css
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  /* Set a transparent border */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

#cellContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 4px solid #000;
  /* Set an outline for the container */
}

#gameContainer {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Permanent Marker", cursive;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Itim&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="gameContainer">
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div id="cellContainer">
    <div cellIndex="0" class="cell">X</div>
    <div cellIndex="1" class="cell">O</div>
    <div cellIndex="2" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="3" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="4" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="5" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="6" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="7" class="cell"></div>
    <div cellIndex="8" class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OJqdMbL?editors=1100)