# Flexbox - rectangle with text on left and image on right

Tags: css, flexbox

Producing a dashboard which has a column filled with rectangles to access different applications.

Each application is represented as a grey rectangle which contains the application name and an image.

Currently it looks like this. The vertical alignment of everything being in the centre is exactly what I want. But I want the image to appear on the right of the rectangle (see final screenshot on the post).

[image]

The markup for an individual app box looks like this

```
<div class="apps-container">

   <a href="#">
       <div class="apps-container__app-box">
           <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
               <h4>App name</h4>
               <img src="app-logo.svg">
           </div>
       </div>
   </a>

   <!-- Other apps in equivalent .apps-container__app-box -->

</div>
```

Anywhere on the grey rectangle should be clickable to access the app which is why it's surrounded with an `<a href>`. The CSS for that `a` element contains

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

If that CSS is removed then it renders vertically at the top of the box rather than the centre like so.

[image]

Inside `.apps-container__app-box` the app name and image are inside a `<div>`. I added some inline CSS where I've tried various things. Currently it's set to `display: flex; align-items: center;` which is *the same rules* as the parent `<a href>`. If I remove that inline CSS it goes back to how it's shown on the second screenshot where the vertical alignment is no longer in the centre.

I took the approach of using a "flexbox inside a flexbox" from [How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311541/how-to-vertically-align-text-inside-a-flexbox)

I don't understand how to do this, or why changing *either* of these rules is affecting it in the same way. I thought that rules could be used independently, i.e. using the parent `<a href>` to do the vertical centre and then some other rules on `.apps-container__app-box` to control the layout of the text and image.

The desired output should look like this:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this help https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ?

Comment: No. I'd read that before posting.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/oyb4w27q/2/ `justify-content` does the trick ;).

Comment: But you're having to define `width` and `height` twice? Both on `.apps-container__app-box` and then the same rules inline, inside the child `<div>`. That can't be right surely?

Comment: Did have a typo even, Thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/oyb4w27q/3/  On which element do you have the `border`? 

Comment: The `border` is currently on the parent `<a>`

Comment: This is without `width` and `height`  https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/oyb4w27q/4/ .

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS/style you need is:

```
justify-content: space-between
```

But in order to see the changes clearly reflected you would need the div to have a width, for example, 200px.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the flex grow on the elements inside the flex container.

Default flex-grow is 0.

If you put for example `flex: 1` on the h4, it will grow to fill the parent correctly and have your desired behavior.