# Select all pseudo elements and classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

There are a bunch of pseudo elements and classes:

[Pseudo Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

> ::after, ::before, ::first-letter, ::first-line, ::selection, ::backdrop

[Pseudo Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes):

> :active, :checked, :default, :dir(), :disabled, :empty, :enabled, :first, :first-child, :first-of-type, :fullscreen, :focus, :hover, :indeterminate, :in-range, :invalid, :lang(), :last-child, :last-of-type, :left, :link, :not(), :nth-child(), :nth-last-child(), :nth-last-of-type(), :nth-of-type(), :only-child, :only-of-type, :optional, :out-of-range, :read-only, :read-write, :required, :right, :root, :scope, :target, :valid, :visited

And there also others like ::-webkit-input-placeholder, ::-moz-placeholder and so on. I don't know what elements they are. But I think they are pseudo elements as it has double colons.

There's an asterisk selector `*` to select all elements that are inside [DOM-Tree](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html).

Now, I'm curious to know why there's no single selector for selecting all pseudo elements and pseudo classes that are outside the DOM-Tree even in css3 or css4?

```
*pseudo{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` selects any element regardless of its nature or state. In this way, it already covers all pseudo-classes, just with zero specificity.

For example, `*` will match any element regardless of whether it is `:first-child`, `:last-child`, or both (which itself can be expressed using either `:only-child` or `:first-child:last-child`). It will also match any link whether it is unvisited (`:link`) or visited (`:visited`), and whether or not it matches one or more of `:hover`/`:active`/`:focus`.

If you're looking for a way to override any and all CSS rules with pseudo-classes for a given element (which can be useful in the case of dynamic pseudo-classes such as the one for links), the only ways are to use an ID selector, an inline style attribute, or `!important`.

`*` doesn't match pseudo-elements because it is a [simple selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#simple), and a simple selector only matches actual elements. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794545/universal-selector-and-pseudo-elements) for a detailed explanation.

The likely reason that there isn't a selector for matching all pseudo-elements is because it doesn't make sense to have one, since different pseudo-elements work differently and have different restrictions as to which CSS properties may be applied to them. For example, `content` and `display` don't apply to `::first-letter`, `::first-line` or `::selection`. But the universal selector exists because elements themselves don't define what CSS properties are applicable ([not usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481944/why-do-fieldsets-clear-floats/6482054#6482054), anyway); as far as CSS is concerned, every *element* is more or less equal.

Comment: I don't think so. If you see question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317238/why-use-selector-in-combination-with-before-and-after/31317299#31317299) will understand... * doesn't select pseudo elements.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: That is what BoltClock is also saying. A simple selector only matches **actual** elements.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note I needed to select an element with was already styled using a pseudo class. But pseudo classes have higher specificity than elements, so I wasn't able to override without using `!important`. I finally figured out I could prefix by selector with `:root` which doesn't really change the selector in any other way other than to increase it's pseudo class specificity.