# CSS selector "*:before"

Tags: css

I am reading a CSS book and come cross the following snippet,

```html
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

My understanding of * is that it selects all the elements. So I do not get what is *:before and *:after.

Also the book says, the snippet above applies border-box sizing to every element by default, without affecting the box-sizing behavior of existing parts of your project. I also do not quite understand this. Hope someone can help me explain.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Thank you. But I still a bit confused. I think all the things we author for a page reside within <html></html>. Wonder what is the difference between html {} and *, *:before, *:after {}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794545/universal-selector-and-pseudo-elements