# Asterisk doesn't select everything, atleast not 'moz-focus-inner'

Tags: css

Here's my CSS:

```
* {
    border: none;
}
```

Now, I thought an asterisk means everything, apparently it didn't for `::-moz-focus-inner`, which means I have to do it like this:

```
* {
    border: none;
}

*::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: That's because you're using a pseudoelement... `*` selects all elements, not including pseudoelements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Andrew Li, the universal `*` selector selects only elements. It's a simple element selector targets only actual elements on the page. Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794545/universal-selector-and-pseudo-elements) with great nuggets of information in the answers and comments.

One answer points to the universal selector [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) (**emphasis mine**):

> The universal selector, written "*", matches the name of any element type. It matches any single element **in the document tree**.

That last bit excludes pseudo elements like `::-moz-focus-inner`, `:before`, and `:after` that are not in the document tree.

---

If you want to optimize your code *a little*, you could move towards something like this:

```
*,
*::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}
```