# Universal selector overrides :link and :any-link:active (CSS)

Tags: css, css-selectors

How come the universal selector (*) overrides the Firefox browser's default styles for the :link and :any-link:active pseudo-class selectors, though it has a specificity of 0?

`*{color: red}` *beats* `:any-link:active{color:activetext}`and `:link{color: linktext}` set by Firefox.

It's the same with Chrome by the way.

Comment: https://bitsofco.de/the-effect-of-importance-and-origin-on-specificity/

Comment: @CBroe: Thank you very much. The explanation in the article sounds very reasonable. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The browser default styles are of the user-agent origin which is always [lower in precedence](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#cascade-sort) than author origin styles, regardless of specificity (notwithstanding `!important`, which *upends* this order).

Answer (score -1):

The Universal Selector is [a simple selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794545/universal-selector-and-pseudo-elements) and is usually set as a "last resort"/ fallback for CSS compilers.

With testing, on Firefox, I **DO NOT SEE** in my own codes and example below that `*` beats either of the pseudo-classes you reference.

```css
:any-link {
  color: brown;
  font-weight:bold;
}

* {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>horses and trees <a href='https://webzoom.freewebs.com/schazaars/11612%20indian%20horses%20052.JPG'>whoopieee!</a></div>
</body>
```

See the example above shows that the anchor is a different colour from the rest of the text, which is expressedly opposite to what you claim, that the `*` element overrides the pseudo-class.

Also note that cascade doesn't effect this; it's to do with the specificity of the elements themselves.

Comment: _"With testing, on Firefox, I DO NOT SEE in my own codes and example below that * beats either of the pseudo-classes you reference."_ - not in this scenario, where both rules have the same origin. But if the `:any-link` comes from the user agent stylesheet, things are different. (https://bitsofco.de/the-effect-of-importance-and-origin-on-specificity/)

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 a {
     color: red;
   }
}
```

as firefox has its own set of default CSS in the browser.

Comment: OP states this issue occurs on other browsers as well, so it's not a Firefox specific issue. Also on my firefox this issue does not appear, so it doesn't even seem to be a browser issue at all.