# Purpose of :before and :after selectors in footer positioning

Tags: css

I'm working with some CSS code to keep a footer at the bottom of the page no matter the content, device, browser, etc. I'm wondering though why the :before and :after selectors are needed:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

To see all the code: https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542579/purpose-of-before-after-css-snippet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794545/universal-selector-and-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 3):

In that example the `:before` and `:after` selectors are not being used for the footer positioning, but it is just part of a reset the author used to ensure that everything is `box-sizing: border-box`